error creating RDOSession - 8007007e The specified module could not be found
I'm getting the following error on one PC only when trying to create an RDOSession:
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {29AB7A12-B531-450E-8F7A-EA94C2F3C05F} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)
The same code/MSI install runs fine on other machines.
 private void CheckForMeetingUpdates() 
 {
     DateTime runStartTime = DateTime.Now;
     RDOSession session = null;
     RDOFolder2 folder = null;
     RDOItems calitems = null;

     try
     {
         session = new RDOSession(); // EXCEPTION On THIS LINE
         if (!session.LoggedOn)
         {
             session.Logon(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false, true, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, false);
         }

         DateTime start1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(0);
         DateTime end1 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
         folder = (RDOFolder2)session.GetDefaultFolder(rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
         calitems = folder.GetActivitiesForTimeRange(start1, end1, true);

I've tried manually installing Redemption using the installer. Also tried manually running regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Redemption\Redemption64.dll". The redemption64.dll exists in the application folder as well. After searching around, it sounds like this error means the dll cannot be found. We have been doing a lot of testing on this PC so something might have become corrupted just not sure what else to try.

This usually happens if Outlook is not installed - please make sure you have the desktop version of Outlook, not just the new webview based Outlook app.

Thanks for the quick reply! It is installed but perhaps there is something off with the installation. I'll try to remove it, reboot and reinstall and report back.

Unfortunately, the uninstall and reinstall of the full office 365 clients results in the same error. Is it possible the redemption dll is somehow registered incorrectly or referencing the wrong path somehow on this one machine? I did change my app from 32 bit to 64 bit so now I'm using the redemption64.dll and registering it during my install. The install works fine on other test machines but fails on this one. Just wondering if you have any other thoughts on what to check.

Please send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.

I think the issue was that we manually registered the Redemption dll on this particular machine at one point and later changed the application from a 32-bit application to a 64-bit application. Somehow the reference in the registry was off and we ran the steps below to resolve the issue although I'm not sure which step actually resolved the problem.
From and Administrators PowerShell prompt. Change directory to C:\Windows\System32 and run

.\regsvr32.exe -u C:\PATH_TO_DLL\Redemption64.dll

.\regsvr32.exe -u C:\PATH_TO_DLL\Redemption.dll


Change directory to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and run

.\regsvr32.exe -u C:\PATH_TO_DLL\Redemption.dll

.\regsvr32.exe -u C:\PATH_TO_DLL\Redemption64.dll

Reboot

Remove all Redemption files from the machine and reboot

Search the registry for any residual entries where a redemption dll is still being referenced.


What we searched for-
29AB7A12-B531-450E-8F7A-EA94C2F3C05F
Interop.Redemption.dll
Redemption.dll
Redemption64.dll
Delete the parent key at the GUID level (eg.- 29AB7A12-B531-450E-8F7A-EA94C2F3C05F) if it is below the CLSID key. Example
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID{29AB7A12-B531-450E-8F7A-EA94C2F3C05F}\InprocServer32

Reboot

Reinstalled application which self-registers the Redemption dll


